# How to prevent: `CIFS: Unknown mount option "defaults"`?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, non-root-user, cifs

Context: I want to enable a normal user to mount a certain cifs mount on his system (Debian Strech). I therefore added the following entry in */etc/fstab* (note the added `,user` in the options):

```
//server/share/ /home/user/mountpoint cifs defaults,user,uid=user,credentials=/home/user/.cifs-creds 0 0
```

Also the credential-file is owned by the user and is readable/writable/executable (700).

Subsequently mounting as *root* works (i.e. cifs-utils are available on the system, the credential-file exists and is correctly populated)! But mounting as a *user* does not, resulting in the following output:

```
user@system: ~$ mount mountpoint
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

*/var/log/kern.log* states:

```
Jun  4 11:36:52 system kernel: [173283.233509] CIFS: Unknown mount option "defaults"
```

So, somehow, when executed as a user, the `defaults` option can not be used to mount? When the `,defaults` option is removed from the fstab entry, users *can* mount (without error) but that would leave out a lot defaults (and using the defaults (other than: ,user) *should* be possible right?).

Hence my question:

- **What is the advised fstab entry to have users mount a CIFS/SAMBA share to prevent the `mount error(22): Invalid argument` caused by the `CIFS: Unknown mount option "defaults"`?**

Should I simply leave out `,defaults` or is there another method to do this (I tried Googling on this, but every tutorial / explanation I find seems to confirm the method used)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page describes `defaults` as refering to the defaults used for axes like `ro`/`rw`, `suid`/`nosuid`, when a value is not specified explicitly.

But the *reason* for using `defaults`, is when you don't have *any* option you want to explicitly specify.  You still need some value to put in the options field, so that you can put something in the next field.

Therefore `,defaults` should never be necessary.